# How can Javascript file fetch data from JSON file

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am currently using Protractor to test a certain website and I want to get one of the values from login-page-path.json to be passed as an argument in login.po.js

here is my login-page-path.json

```
{
    "loginPagePath": {
        "emailPath": "iEmail",
        "passPath": "inputPassword",
        "loginPath": "btnContinue"
    }
}
```

here is my login.po.js

```
module.exports = {

    inputEmail: (value) => {
        var emailPath = element(by.id("iEmail"));
        emailPath.sendKeys(value);
    },

    inputPassword: (value) => {
        var passPath = element(by.id("inputPassword"));
        passPath.sendKeys(value);
    },

    clickLoginButton: () => {
        var submitPath = element(by.className("btnContinue"));
        submitPath.click();
    }
}
```

here is my login.spec.js

```
let specPage = require('../page_objects/login.po.js');


describe('hello secret', function() {
    it('log in successfully', function() {
    
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('https://hello.secret.net/login');
    
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.sleep(5000);

    specPage.inputEmail('secret@gmail.com');
    browser.sleep(5000);

    specPage.inputPassword('secret');
    browser.sleep(5000);
      
    });
  });
```

i Want my login.po.js to be looked like this. The **loginPagePath.emailPath**, **loginPagePath.passPath** and **loginPagePath.loginPath** value from JSON file will be passed to those arguments

```
module.exports = {

    inputEmail: (value) => {
        var emailPath = element(by.id(loginPagePath.emailPath));
        emailPath.sendKeys(value);
    },

    inputPassword: (value) => {
        var passPath = element(by.id(loginPagePath.passPath));
        passPath.sendKeys(value);
    },

    clickLoginButton: () => {
        var submitPath = element(by.className(loginPagePath.loginPath));
        submitPath.click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let specPage = require('../page_objects/login.po');
```

is enough and file extension is not required

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming login-page-path.json is in same directory as of login.po.js (else change path accordingily):**

```
let loginPagePath =  require("./login-page-path.json").loginPagePath 
module.exports = {

    inputEmail: (value) => {
        var emailPath = element(by.id(loginPagePath.emailPath));
        emailPath.sendKeys(value);
    },

    inputPassword: (value) => {
        var passPath = element(by.id(loginPagePath.passPath));
        passPath.sendKeys(value);
    },

    clickLoginButton: () => {
        var submitPath = element(by.className(loginPagePath.loginPath));
        submitPath.click();
    }
}
```